# Cannot find the main class after converting java project to maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a very simple HelloWorld code in Java which works ok.  I'm using Eclipse and trying to figure out how to import dependencies for a project with the maven2 eclipse plugin.

```
    public class testMavenDep {

        public static void main(String arg[]){
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

However, when I right click on the project > configure > convert to maven project, and then try and run it gives me an error message saying...

> Could not find the main class: testMavenDep.testMavenDep.  Program will exit.

And the following in the console...

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testMavenDep/testMavenDep
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testMavenDep.testMavenDep
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   Exception in thread "main"

My pom file is...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>testMavenDep</groupId>
  <artifactId>testMavenDep</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

My question is, for an already existing Java Project, what is the proper way to add maven dependencies?  I can add the dependencies using the above method but I'm getting issues with it losing track of the main class.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You ask about maven but don't include your POM file...

Comment: My apologies... it's attached now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the source folder that you are putting your main class in?  By default, Eclipse puts it in src, but maven conventions are src/main/java.  It could be that adding maven dependencies is changing your source folders so that your class is not compiled.

Comment: Yes this is what was happening.  Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, what exactly is the solution here ? I moved my source files to src/main/java but i get the same error as you do.